# cannot change colour of label in <DrawerItem> react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

As given in the code, I have tried and I wanted if the "Home" displaying in Drawer can become white by chance?

```
<Drawer.Section style={{backgroundColor:"green"}}>
            <DrawerItem 
              icon={({ color, size }) => (
                <Icon name="home-outline" color={"white"} size={size}/>
              )}
              label="Home"
              color="white" //as this is not working
              onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate("Home");
              }}
            />
    </Drawer.Section>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no property for color, you have the below props to style your DrawerItem

- `activeTintColor`: Color for the icon and label when the item is
  active.
- `inactiveTintColor`: Color for the icon and label when the item is inactive.
- `activeBackgroundColor`: Background color for item when it's active.
- `inactiveBackgroundColor`: Background color for item when
  it's inactive.
- `labelStyle`: Style object for the label Text.
- `style`: Style object for the wrapper View.

Comment: is it possible if the color of title can be changed too <Drawer.Section title="Preferences"/> i.e. Preferences? @Guruparan Giritharan

Comment: I couldnt find a reference for Drawer.Section is it a custom component ?

Comment: its in the `react-native-paper`

Comment: From what i see it takes the color from the theme, you will have to go through the theme to change it

Comment: only style works but color prop in style object does not work instead I tried 

label={<Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>First Item</Text>} and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

We can change Drawer.Section title color using this

```
            <Drawer.Section
              title={
                <Text style={{color: colors.textColor}}>Preferences</Text>
              }>
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution, but it isn't pretty:

```
<DrawerItem 
  icon={ () => ( <Icon name='bike' color='white' size={24} onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('Home') }} /> )} 

  label={ () => ( <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 20}}>Start Motor</Text>) }

  onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('Home') }}          
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Drawer.Item you can use below code.

```
label={<Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>First Item</Text>}
```

For Drawer.Section you can use below code.

```
title={<Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}> Welcome</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define theme like this :

```
const themePaper =  {
  colors:{
    text: '#fff',
  }
}
```

and then you can use it for `Drawer.Section` and `Drawer.Item` easily

```
<Drawer.Section
  theme = {themePaper}
>
```

and

```
<Drawer.Item
  theme = {themePaper}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the onSurfaceVariant prop inside theme to change the label color

```
        <Drawer.Item
          theme={{
            colors: {
              onSurfaceVariant: 'red',
            },
          }}
        />
```